# Play Java 2.3.8 deduplicate on sbt-assembly

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt-assembly

**The question: why is it ignoring the MergeStrategy.first?**

I've made a minor application within the Play Framework using version 2.3.8
According to the official documentation you can add the line `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")`to the plugin.sbt and add a few (see code below) to use the `activator assembly` command.

This seems to be working but there is a deduplicate conflict. This happens strangely with the file ServerWithStop.class. In the build.sbt there is an assembleMergeStrategy for this class. This is an exact copy of the official documentation.

```
case "play/core/server/ServerWithStop.class" => MergeStrategy.first
case other => (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value(other)
```

I've added a few lines that I found to fix the spring.tooling deduplicates (which can be found again in the full sbt).
I understand the principles; its hashing SHA-1 to compare the classes then merge according to the behaviour, I understand that it doesn't understand what to do with the duplicates that seem to be different with ServerWithStop.class.

What I dont understand (and thus the question): why is it ignoring the MergeStrategy.first?

-

*build.sbt*

```
name := """MovieRequest"""

version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.35"
)

mainClass in assembly := Some("play.core.server.NettyServer")

fullClasspath in assembly += Attributed.blank(PlayKeys.playPackageAssets.value)

assemblyExcludedJars in assembly <<= (fullClasspath in assembly) map { cp =>
  cp filter {x => x.data.getName.matches("sbt.*") || x.data.getName.matches(".*macros.*")}
}

// Exclude commons-logging because it conflicts with the jcl-over-slf4j
libraryDependencies ~= { _ map {
  case m if m.organization == "com.typesafe.play" =>
m.exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging")
  case m => m
}}

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x if Assembly.isConfigFile(x) =>
    MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if Assembly.isReadme(ps.last) || Assembly.isLicenseFile(ps.last) =>
MergeStrategy.rename
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
(xs map {_.toLowerCase}) match {
  case ("manifest.mf" :: Nil) | ("index.list" :: Nil) | ("dependencies" :: Nil) =>
    MergeStrategy.discard
      case ps @ (x :: xs) if ps.last.endsWith(".sf") || ps.last.endsWith(".dsa")     =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "plexus" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "spring.tooling" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "services" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case ("spring.schemas" :: Nil) | ("spring.handlers" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case _ => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
    }
  case "asm-license.txt" | "overview.html" => MergeStrategy.discard

  // Take the first ServerWithStop because it's packaged into two jars
  case "play/core/server/ServerWithStop.class" => MergeStrategy.first
  case other => (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value(other)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the built-in `dist` command? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionDist

Comment: `dist` produces different output; it creates a ZIP file, whereas `sbt assembly` creates a fat JAR that you can run using `java -jar my_filename.jar`.